# Trello doesn't move cards between lists using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, trello

I think I have try all the solutions around here, and none of them worked for me.

The problem is that I can't move cards between list using the trello api. I have tried this ways to do it:
Number 1:

```
var API_KEY = '********************************';
var TOKEN = '************************************************************';
var ID_LIST = '***************************';

  var payload = {
    "value": ID_LIST,
    "token": TOKEN,
    "key": API_KEY
  };
  var options = {
    "method": "PUT",
    "payload": payload
  };
  // Post the payload to Trello
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://api.trello.com/1/cards/[id of my card]/idList', options);
    Logger.log(response);
  } catch (e) {
    // Log any errors 
    Logger.log("ERROR:\n"+e.message);
  }
```

Number 2:

```
function createOAthService_Trello() {

  var consumerKey='*************************';
  var consumerSecret = '********************************************************'

  var service = OAuth1.createService("trello");
  service.setAccessTokenUrl("https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  service.setRequestTokenUrl("https://trello.com/1/OAuthGetRequestToken");
  service.setAuthorizationUrl("https://trello.com/1/OAuthAuthorizeToken?scope=read,write");
  service.setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties());

  service.setCallbackFunction('authCallback_Trello');

  service.setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
  service.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);

  return service;
}



function checkServiceAccess(){
      var service = createOAthService_Trello();
      var emailAddress ='*****@********.com';

      if(service.hasAccess()){
        return service;
    }
    else {
      var authorizationUrl = service.authorize();
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, 'Google Script App Needs Authorization (Trello)', 'Please visit the following URL and then re-run the script: ' + authorizationUrl);
      Logger.log('Please visit the following URL and then re-run the script: ' + authorizationUrl);
  }
}
function moveCard(){
      var service = checkServiceAccess();
      var url = 'http://api.trello.com/1/cards/[myCardId]/idList?value=[newListId]&token=[myToken]&cards=open&lists=open'
      var options = {"method" : "put"};

      var raw= service.fetch(url, options);
      Logger.log(raw);
}
```

This two pieces of code doesn't crash. But they don't move any card, and only return a Log with the ID of the list where they are placed.
I have checked a thousand of times for the id's to be correct, so that can't be the problem. 
It doesn't seem to be a problem with the PUT request, because I can Update descriptions, titles,... But with the DELETE request,it fires a "Unexpected exception". Maybe they are related.

Also, I have tried to insert this on my code:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://trello.com/1/client.js?key=*****************************"></script>
</html>

//eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://trello.com/1/client.js?key=************************').getContentText());

var success = function(successMsg) {
  asyncOutput(successMsg);
};

var error = function(errorMsg) {
  asyncOutput(errorMsg);
};

Logger.log(Trello.get('/member/me/boards', success, error));
```

But it crash because it can't find the Trello global variable.
I'm really desperate, any help will be apreciated .
Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: if you can succeed with other trello calls, most likely you have a mistake in the api usage. the last attempt  cant work because the trello library is for frontend use, not backend use.

Comment: I thought it could be that, so I tried at Trello's sandbox, and it worked. But they use the global Trello object...

Comment: you  can try using chrome debugger to make api calls with JavaScript in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Someone from Trello helped me with this. So, if you are having the same problem, just change the Url from:

```
http://api.trello.com/1/cards/[myCardId]/idList?value=[newListId]&token=[myToken]&cards=open&lists=open
```

to:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/cards/[myCardId]/idList?value=[newListId]&token=[myToken]&cards=open&lists=open
```

It seems that Trello take all put and post made at **http://** as GET. Using **https://** instead solve the problem.

Comment: this really saved me!